# Encontrar Palabra dentro de un Foreach

Tags: php, condiciones, foreach, else

Tengo un foreach el cual me trae multiples campos de la base de datos en este momento los muestro con un echo y efectivamente tengo todos los datos dentro de una variable llamada rol

```
foreach ($list_rol as $rol) {
                echo $rol["accion"] . ",";
            }
```

Resultado del foreach:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ahora lo que necesito es crear una card por cada palabra que tengo en el foreach es decir se crea una card por Cotizaciones,RespuestasRapidas, ETC... Ya lo he intentado forzando la variable

```
$rol = ['Cotizaciones'];
            $rol2 = ['RespuestasRapidas'];

?php
                if ($rol ==['Cotizaciones']) {
                ?>
                    <!-- Seccion Admin Producto -->
                    <div class="card text-center me-3" style="width: 18rem;">
                        <a href="<?= URL_VIEW ?>gestion_producto_view.php?fk=1">
                            <div class="card-body" name="">
                                <i class="bbi bi-cart-plus fs-3"></i>
                                <h5 class="card-title">Crear Producto</h5>
                                <p class="card-text text-muted">Gestion Inventario</p>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                <?php
                }  if ($rol2 == ['RespuestasRapidas']) { ?>
                    <!-- Seccion Comercial -->
                    <div class="card text-center me-3" style="width: 18rem;">
                        <a href="<?= URL_VIEW ?>gestion_factura_proforma_view.php">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <i class="bi  bi-receipt fs-3"></i>
                                <h5 class="card-title">Factura Pro-Forma</h5>
                                <p class="card-text text-muted">Facturacion</p>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                <?php
                }
```

el hace esto bien pero no puedo definir todas las variables ya que son valores de la base de datos dependiendo de cada usuario

Comment: ¿Hay cosas que cambian en cada Card según el contenido de cada valor? No necesitas los `if`, sino ir creando cada Card concatenando y decidiendo aquello que sea distinto según cada valor. Es un detalle importante que no explicas en tu pregunta.

Comment: Respondiendo a tu pregunta, si cambia el if porque las variables las estoy definiendo pero lo que decia yo en mi pregunta a lo ultimo, es que no puedo definir todas las variables ya que son valores de la base de datos dependiendo de cada usuario

Comment: No entiendo... Has dicho que quieres crear una Card por cada valor que haya en el `foreach`, ¿no es eso? Entonces, crea cada Card concatenando, no con `if`. ¿Qué sentido tienen los `if` ahí?

Comment: Es necesario el IF ya que cada CARD trae un enlace y un titulo distinto

Comment: Y dónde están guardados esos títulos y enlaces? En tu pregunta sólo hablas de los campos que te dan (`$list_rol`). En qué array u otra estructura de datos está almacenado lo que quieres mostrar en las cartas?

Comment: Se supone que ese enlace y ese título que correspondería a cada Card según el valor está en alguna parte, sea en la base de datos, sea en un array que escribirás a mano, asociando cada valor. Si está en la BD deberás traerlo y si no existe puedes definir un array que asocie esos datos por cada valor, buscándolos luego en la lectura de datos. Tu principal problema aquí es implementar una lógica equivocada, la cual hace que un problema muy simple parezca complicado.

Answer (score 1):

En tu comentario dices:

> Es necesario el IF ya que cada CARD trae un enlace y un titulo
> distinto

Se supone que ese enlace y ese título que correspondería a cada Card según el valor **está en alguna parte**, sea en la base de datos, sea en un array que escribirás a mano, asociando cada valor.

Si está en la BD deberás traerlo y si no existe puedes definir un array que asocie esos datos por cada valor, buscándolos luego en la lectura de datos. Tu principal problema aquí es implementar una lógica equivocada, la cual hace que un problema muy simple parezca complicado.

Te pondré un ejemplo, asumiendo que el valor no está en la base de datos. Si tal es el caso, lo puedes resolver escribiendo un array que asocie a cada valor la url, el título y lo que haga falta.

El código quedaría así:

[<kbd>VER DEMO EN REXTESTER.</kbd>](https://rextester.com/KYJCLQ46997)

```
/*
    Este array asocia cada valor distinto 
    según los diferentes action ...
    Como dije, esto podría existir en la BD
    */
$mData=array
    (
        'Cotizaciones'=>array
        (
            'url'=>'gestion_producto_view.php?fk=1',
            'iClass'=>'bbi bi-cart-plus fs-3',
            'text'=>'Crear Producto',
            'title'=>'Gestion Inventario'          
        ),
        'RespuestasRapidas'=>array
        (
            'url'=>'gestion_factura_proforma_view.php',
            'iClass'=>'bi bi-receipt fs-3',
            'text'=>'Factura Pro-Forma',
            'title'=>'Facturación'

        ),
        'FacturacionComercial'=>array
        (
            'url'=>'AQUI-LA-URL-PARA-FACTURA',
            'iClass'=>'bi bi-clase-que-sea',
            'text'=>'Text para FC',
            'title'=>'Título para FC'
        ),    
    );

/*
    Construimos una plantilla con marcadores %s
    a fin de ir sustituyendo cada valor dinámico
    */
$template=
    "<div class=\"card text-center me-3\" style=\"width: 18rem;\">
        <a href=\"%s%s\">
            <div class=\"card-body\" name=\"\">
                <i class=\"%s\"></i>
                <h5 class=\"card-title\">%s</h5>
                <p class=\"card-text text-muted\">%s</p>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>";


# Esto simula los resultados de tu consulta SQL para fines de prueba
$list_rol=array
    (
        array('accion'=>'Cotizaciones'),
        array('accion'=>'RespuestasRapidas'),
        array('accion'=>'FacturacionComercial')
     );

# Esto simula tu constante URL_VIEW para fines de prueba
define('URL_VIEW', 'https://www.example.com/');

# Variable para ir cocantenado
$html="";
foreach ($list_rol as $rol) 
{
    $accion=$rol["accion"];
    $html.=sprintf($template,
                       URL_VIEW,
                       $mData[$accion]['url'],
                       $mData[$accion]['iClass'],
                       $mData[$accion]['text'],
                       $mData[$accion]['title']
                   );           
}

echo $html;
```

**Salida:**

```
<div class="card text-center me-3" style="width: 18rem;">
        <a href="https://www.example.com/gestion_producto_view.php?fk=1">
            <div class="card-body" name="">
                <i class="bbi bi-cart-plus fs-3"></i>
                <h5 class="card-title">Crear Producto</h5>
                <p class="card-text text-muted">Gestion Inventario</p>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div><div class="card text-center me-3" style="width: 18rem;">
        <a href="https://www.example.com/gestion_factura_proforma_view.php">
            <div class="card-body" name="">
                <i class="bi bi-receipt fs-3"></i>
                <h5 class="card-title">Factura Pro-Forma</h5>
                <p class="card-text text-muted">Facturación</p>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div><div class="card text-center me-3" style="width: 18rem;">
        <a href="https://www.example.com/AQUI-LA-URL-PARA-FACTURA">
            <div class="card-body" name="">
                <i class="bi bi-clase-que-sea"></i>
                <h5 class="card-title">Text para FC</h5>
                <p class="card-text text-muted">Título para FC</p>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
```

---

La lógica definida en `$mData` de forma programática, puede definirse también en el modelo de datos.

Así, podrías tener una tabla con estos datos:

```
accion                 url                                 iClass                   text                 title 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Cotizaciones           gestion_producto_view.php?fk=1      bbi bi-cart-plus fs-3    Crear Producto       Gestion Inventario
RespuestasRapidas      gestion_factura_proforma_view.php   bi bi-receipt fs-3       Factura Pro-Forma    Facturación    
FacturacionComercial   AQUI-LA-URL-PARA-FACTURA            bi bi-clase-que-sea      Text para FC         Título para FC
```

En este caso los valores vendrían en la consulta, como una columna más, la cual plasmarías en tu plantilla. Esto podría ser particularmente útil en un contexto más amplio, pues tendrías reflejada la lógica en tu modelo de datos y no tendrías que crear un array `$mData` que sería enorme.

Son simplemente dos formas de organizar el contexto, puedes optar por la que mejor te convenga.